# How to parse JSON in javascript when the value itself is a JSON internally

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{ 
   "key1" : "value",
   "key2" : "{ "innerkey1": "value", "innerkey2": "value"}"
}
```

Example code:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(data);
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $grouplist = $('#groups');
   $('<li>' + myData.key1 + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
});
```

If I call `JSON.parse` for the above function, I am getting parse error in console.

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/2L8dLtfq/

Comment: You can't parse JSON that isn't JSON.

Comment: You'll have to fix the data. There's no way for a script to fix itself if its syntax is invalid. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: If you really need to have that inner string be a JSON string, you need to use backslashes to escape the quotation marks: `{"key2": "{ \"innerKey\": \"innerValue\"}"}`. Then you'll need to parse that inner JSON string after parsing the entire JSON. But if all you need is a nested data structure, get rid of the inner JSON string: `{"key2": { "innerKey": "innerValue" } }`

Comment: Corrected the typo. But in my case the json response is coming from another service call. And it is a very big json response. And as you said Sunil D., removing the quotes will not work for me,as I am getting the data in such a format from the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript interpreter has already parsed it for you so you don't need to parse again

```
var ss = { 
 "key1" : "value",
 "key2" : { "innerkey1": "value", "innerkey2": "value"}
};
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $grouplist = $('#groups');
   $('<li>' + ss.key2 + '</li>').appendTo($grouplist);
});
```

you can directly use value by key name `ss.key1` or `ss.key2` but key2 return an object again so you can use access by key name again like this`ss.key2.innerkey1`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L8dLtfq/4/)

Comment: Have one more doubt related to what you explained for javascript interpreter. In the scenario where I am getting the service json response (ss) as a string parameter, will the same logic work ? I kind of tried that way before, but don't recall that working.

Comment: If you have an array of JSON bject  ss = [{}.{},{}] then you have to parse it, other wise it already parsed, and for passing as a string can you put code here what you trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quotation mark (") in your input.

```
{ "key1" : "value", "key2" : "{ "innerkey1": "value", "innerkey2": "value"} }
-----------------------------^ here
```

Comment: Corrected that. Sorry for the typo